# How to run cram-highlevel?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I download cram-highlevel on http://code.in.tum.de/indefero/index.php//p/cram-highlevel/source/tree/ros_electric/

Here is the download link:http://code.in.tum.de/indefero/index.php//p/cram-highlevel/source/download/ros_electric/

I rosmake successfully.

I also have tried all the launch file seems nothing happened.

Where I can start?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12041/how-to-run-cram-highlevel?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly are you trying to do? cram_highlevel is at the moment just a random collection of lisp libraries for all different kinds of functionality.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-11-22**:
I want to use cram to make pr2 grasp a cup or similar scenarios on simulations.Where can I start?